# com.squareup.picasso returns empty (gray) image after resize

Tags: android, picasso, image-resizing

I have an imagepicker in my app and after I picked an image from an `Intent.ACTION_PICK` I wan´t to show it in a small thumbnail.

For image resizing and so on I use Picasso like this:

```
screenshot.post(() -> Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(Uri.parse(newState.attachmentUri))
                    .resize(screenshot.getWidth(), screenshot.getHeight())
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(screenshot));
```

Now I get Bugreports that this thumbnail remains empty (light gray). I couldn´t recreate the issue until I found an image in my gallery that creates the same issue.

I found out that this are images that where made with an effect called "focus effect" of the google camera. I cross-checked this by making several photos with this effect and several without. I can reproduce the error with the images with effect and the images without effect are working properly... What could be wrong here?

When I remove the `resize` all works fine..

Can you help me here?

Best regards

Artur

Comment: Can you please confirm whether your `screenshot`object is being created or it's `null`. Before calling the `screenshot.post()` method, please check what you're getting for `screenshot.getWidth(), screenshot.getHeight()`. This may help you troubleshoot the problem

Comment: Idea for workaround- put scaleType= "fitCenter" into the ImageView, and dont use resize/centeInside at all

Comment: @YuDroid screenshot is not null because post is fired. But I checked it in debug also. `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are returning values.

Comment: @X3Btel that would be my solution if we don´t find any other. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This happened for me when the `ImageView` had `android:tint` set to a value in the XML layout.

I guess that some parameters prevent the image from displaying correctly, which include the tint and maybe the resize parameters (according to the comments on your question).

Comment: helped me with fixing the issue! in my case the tint was causing the issue. Thank you